# Prevent defunct of child process when systemctl exits

Tags: linux, background-process, systemctl

I have 1 service registered with systemd

`open_ssh.script`

```
autossh -M 0 -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 -i .ssh/id_rsa USER@HOST -fN
```

`auto_open_ssh.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Tunnel Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=open_ssh.script
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=60s

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After I run the service, I receive the log:

```
Dec 29 11:07:41 ip-10-0-1-231.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal autossh[21036]: starting ssh (count 1)
Dec 29 11:07:41 ip-10-0-1-231.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal autossh[21036]: ssh child pid is 21046
Dec 29 11:07:41 ip-10-0-1-231.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal autossh[21036]: received signal to exit (15)
```

I check processes and don't see the autossh. It seems the service exited and automatically killed the child process (autossh).
Can I prevent autossh to get killed?

Answer (score 2):

When you are running `autossh` as a systemd service, with the default `Type=simple`, you should not use the `-f` option with `autossh`.

If you want to keep using the `-f` option, you should add a `Type=forking` to your service definition.

Also, note that if you run this as a *system service* (i.e. you add your `auto_open_ssh.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/`), it will start autossh with the current working directory set to `/` if you don't tell it otherwise, so you should use a full path for your SSH key file.

If you run this service as an *user service* (configured in `~/.config/systemd/user/auto_open_ssh.service`), `systemd` will stop your user services when your last session logs out, unless you allow your user account to leave processes running when you log out, with `loginctl enable-linger <your_username>`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your suggest. But, when I remove -f ( don't use run background), the ssh still is killed after start service. How to keep ssh connection?

Comment: Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after removing `-f`, to make the service file change effective?

Comment: Yes, I ran daemon-reload and restart service.

Comment: `received signal to exit (15)` suggests that `autossh` is getting killed with SIGTERM. I don't see any reason why `systemd` would do that with your service definition. Is it possible that your AWS EC2 instance has been hacked and rootkitted by an intruder, and the intruder's rootkit would fight with your `autossh`?

Comment: Yes, I will check. 
Currently, I will add an infinite loop after the ssh command to keep the service from exiting.
`autossh -M 0 -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 -i .ssh/id_rsa USER@HOST -fN
  while true; do
   sleep 60
  done
`